# How to get all deprecations in project

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on the project that uses a lot of deprecated classes. Now, when the time has come to refactor it, I was "given the honor" to do it. But, we decided not to remove all the deprecated classes, we still gonna use old android.app.Fragment class and few others. But the problem is that Fragment deprecation warnings are simply overflowing the build stack(when I clean/build) and I cannot see other warings. So, my question is: can I see all the deprections somehow, or maybe I can suppress specific warnings for the entire project?

Comment: in the compiler plugin you can configure the deprecation warn https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#showDeprecation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this will help you..

> - First GOTO **Analyze**  ->
> - Select **Inspect Code..** ->
> - After code has been inspected. Select **JAVA -> Code maturity ->    Depricated API usag**e "List of depricated class will be displayed"

You can find all depricated class in your project easily..